# Performance Impact between databases

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a fairly large table. We want to run grafana queries against this data, and are thinking about dumping the data each day into a separate table/database to minimize performance impact on our main DB.  Ideally, we would have some daily replication dump data as such:

```
database1.table --> database2.table_hist
```

So my question is, would it be better to create a new schema (on the same server) in order to further segregate the datasets? Would we see performance impact on database1 if we're running long queries against database2.table_hist?

Comment: Please clarify your terminology, particularly what you mean by "spin up a new database". What they call a "database" in MySQL is simply a [schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html), i.e. a logical grouping of tables in the same MySQL instance.

Comment: edit to reflect MySQL paradigm

Comment: And now the answer becomes self-evident, doesn't it? A table in the new schema is no different from a table in the old schema, except now you need to add `new_schema.` when referencing it.

Comment: Sorry, no. It's not obvious to me. I know how to reference it, but my question is about the performance impact across different schemas if running long(ish) queries on one of the schemas on the host.  We want to protect schema1.  But if creating schema2 does not accomplish that, then maybe we need to put the historical schema on a different host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same MySQL process will use the same CPU cores to process and move data between the same disk and the same memory, whether your reporting table is in the same MySQL database (schema) or in a different schema. Even if you have a separate MySQL instance on that machine, it will still compete with its sibling for hardware resources. For proper isolation you need a separate server.

A typical scenario includes a master-slave replicated pair, with reporting workload hitting the slave.